# Mac Classic file conversion service

Tags: filemaker, mac-os-classic

I have an old FileMaker Pro 5 file.

According to https://support.claris.com/s/article/Converting-older-FileMaker-Pro-files-to-the-fmp12-file-format-1503693002275?language=en_US ...

...I need to open the file with FileMaker Pro 11 to convert it to the 11 format (so that I can then open it with the current version, 12).

Although I am able to download FileMaker Pro 11 at http://fmdl.filemaker.com/TBUB/eleven/fmp_trial_fm_11.0.4.401b.dmg , I no longer have Mac OS Classic to run it with so that I can save as a version 11 file.

Are there any online (or even offline) services by which I can make a conversion?

Comment: In theory it could be possible to use _SheepShaver_ to run MacOS 9 and doing the conversion there. I cannot currently test this though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only options available to you are:

1. Hire a FileMaker consultant to do it for you, or
2. Use an OS virtualizer like VM Ware or Parallels to install the Mac OS version you need to run FileMaker Pro 11

The conversion from an .fmp5 file to .fmp7 is not as straightforward as conversion from .fmp7 to .fmp12. If you can find a copy of the tool MetaDataMagic from New Millennium it will help make the conversion easier.